# Proving identites with only tan and cot

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I can't figure out how to start this identity or solve it. I began on the right side and distributed but I don't know where to go from there. 
cotA + cotB= cotAcotB (tanB + tan A)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Distribute out the right side, and use the fact that $\cot x \tan x = 1$

Comment: When I distribute I get cotAtanB + cotBtanA where do you go from there?

Comment: @Loren check your distribution again

Comment: No, the first term should be $\cot A \cot B \tan B$

Comment: You get $(\cot A\cot B\tan B) + (\cot A\cot B \tan A)$.  Then you use the fact that Ross Millikan mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to express everything in terms of $\cot$. e.g. $\displaystyle\tan A + \tan B= \frac{1}{\cot A}+\frac{1}{\cot B}=\frac{\cot A+\cot B}{\cot A\cot B}$